# using application data and local settings in windows phone applications

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

My question is if the user closes the app with out selecting logout, in the next app launch the same page should be displayed. If he selects logout before closing the app while he opens the app it should display with login page(with the help of Applicationdata, local settings).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, and you're using a web packager such as Apache Cordova or PhoneGap to make HTML into a mobile app. Then yes, application data will be saved between sessions if you store variables in it. But it's your responsibility in your app to check the contents of the application data when your app loads and display the correct page since the app itself won't necessarily stay loaded.